# Replacement for deprecated class LogStream

Tags: logging, java-8, rmi

I wish to replace code containing the deprecated class LogStream with whatever the better alternative is.

But as per the [Java API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/), there is no replacement provided for this class.

Can someone pls suggest an alternative approach?

Comment: One alternative is to continue using it, and another is to use some logging library such as Log4j.

Comment: It has been deprecated since the days of Java-1.2 (http://www.kbs.twi.tudelft.nl/Documentation/Programming/Java/jdk1.2/api/java/rmi/server/LogStream.html)... But any modern logging framework (apache commons logging, java.util.logging, log4j, logback, to name just a few) has more features than this simple class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most obvious alternative is the [`java.util.logging`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-frame.html) package. But you should use what the rest of your system uses, if anything.